# Seisbench can't download dataset because Firewall

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, data-science

I use anaconda_jupyter notebook for doing some data science stuff, when i want to download the data using

```
data = sbd.Iquique()
```

I face this log

```
2023-08-01 20:50:49,209 | seisbench | WARNING | Check available storage and memory before downloading and general use of Iquique dataset. Dataset size: waveforms.hdf5 ~5Gb, metadata.csv ~2.6Mb
2023-08-01 20:50:50,399 | seisbench | WARNING | Dataset Iquique not in cache.
2023-08-01 20:50:50,399 | seisbench | WARNING | Trying to download preprocessed version from SeisBench repository.
2023-08-01 20:50:51,604 | seisbench | WARNING | The download precheck failed with status code 404. This is not an error itself, but might indicate a subsequent error. If you encounter an error, this might be caused by the firewall setup of your network. Please check https://github.com/seisbench/seisbench#known-issues for details.
2023-08-01 20:50:52,805 | seisbench | WARNING | Dataset Iquique not in SeisBench repository. Starting download and conversion from source.
```

This only occurs in my machine, which still can run in google colab. Anyone has thought for setting firewall or fix this issue?

I was trying open the 2443 Port as in github refers, but still can't